# Jquery & jquery.visible for each element | Animation only on View / visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I'm trying to make animation play only if visible. Therefor, I use jQuery and jquery.visible.js.

I can make this working via `document.getElementsByClassName('parl')[0].style.animationPlayState='running/paused';`

But this way, I have to do it for each item [0]-[5], what I'm trying to avoid, so why `$(this)` is not working?

Thanks to @Tom, we use now `.css().`. Now, our (new) code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
//if first .element is visible
        if ($('.element').visible(true)) {
//Play Animation
      $('.element', this).css("animationPlayState","running");
            }else{
//If not visible stop it
            $('.element', this).css("animationPlayState","paused");

    }
});
```

Now, the scenario is if the first '.element' is in view, jQuery sets all '.element' to pause! Not every element is a switch for itself.

At Codepen [Animation Play/Stop for each element](https://codepen.io/netdoc64/pen/MWVezVd)

Here as HTML code https://www.codepile.net/pile/JyPlNByQ

Comment: What is "not working" about `this`?  What does `this` refer to in this context?  What do you expect it to refer to?  Why?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which fully demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Because the problem is nothing to do with `this` but instead the fact you're expecting a jQuery object to have the properties of an Element object.

Comment: `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'animationPlayState')` means the property *before* animationPlayState is `undefined` - ie `$(this).style === undefined` - because jquery objects don't have a `style` property.  `$(this)[0] === this`   ie there's no problem with `this` or `$(this)` as stated in the title and question - hence the above confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of `.style` :

```js
//Both syntaxes are valid
$(this).css("animationPlayState","running");
$(this).css("animation-play-state","paused");
```